# Regular expression to match a dot

Tags: python, regex

Was wondering what the best way is to match `"test.this"` from `"blah blah blah test.this@gmail.com blah blah"` is? Using Python.

I've tried `re.split(r"\b\w.\w@")`

Comment: `\w` only matches a single character - you probably want `\w+`

Comment: Here's [an email validation regex](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) if you are looking for one.

Comment: See also: [How to fix “<string> DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence” in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335970/how-to-fix-string-deprecationwarning-invalid-escape-sequence-in-python)

Answer (score 249):

A `.` in regex is a metacharacter, it is used to match any character. To match a literal dot in a raw Python string (`r""` or `r''`), you need to escape it, so `r"\."`

Comment: Unless the regular expression is stored inside a regular python string, in which case you need to use a double `\ ` (`\\ `) instead. So, all of these are equivalent: `'\\.'`, `"\\."`, `r'\.'`, `r"\."`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52335971/4561887.

Comment: I went ahead and added an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66666859/4561887.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Minor nitpick--the `r"..."` syntax is Python "raw" strings, not "regular" strings.

Comment: @GrandOpener, correct, as I explain [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66666859/4561887) (please take a look at it). Please re-read my comment above too. I stated that regular strings require the double-slash: `'\\.'`, `"\\."`, while raw strings require the single slash: `r'\.'`, `r"\."`, which was the entire point of my comment. This answer doesn't make that clear. I wanted to make that clear in my comment for anyone stumbling upon this answer who's using regular strings, as this answer is intended for raw strings only.

Comment: @GrandOpener, I've updated Yuushi's answer to make it clear his or her answer applies to raw strings only. Yuushi is welcome to edit his answer and [link to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66666859/4561887) if he wants in order to show how two backslashes are needed for regular strings. (I'm trying to keep my edits to his answer to a minimum.)

Comment: @GabrielStaples Ah I see now what you were saying.  I didn't parse the "unless...in which case" correctly on first reading of your comment.  Never mind then!

Answer (score 60):

In your regex you need to **escape** the dot `"\."` or use it inside a **character class** `"[.]"`, as it is a meta-character in regex, which matches any character.

Also, you need `\w+` instead of `\w` to match one or more word characters.

---

Now, if you want the `test.this` content, then `split` is not what you need. `split` will split your string around the `test.this`. For example:

```
>>> re.split(r"\b\w+\.\w+@", s)
['blah blah blah ', 'gmail.com blah blah']
```

---

You can use [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\w+[.]\w+(?=@)', s)   # look ahead
['test.this']
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+[.]\w+)@', s)     # capture group
['test.this']
```

Comment: +1 for character class. Using gcovr from a Jenkinsfile and trying to exclude dot directories, and Jenkins doesn't understand escape sequences. The character class worked beautifully.

Answer (score 15):

> "In the default mode, Dot (.) matches any character except a newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline." (python Doc)

So, if you want to evaluate dot literaly, I think you should put it in square brackets:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'\b(\w+[.]\w+)')
>>> resp = p.search("blah blah blah test.this@gmail.com blah blah")
>>> resp.group()
'test.this'
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is my add-on to [the main answer by @Yuushi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13989661/4561887):

### Summary

These are NOT allowed.

```py
'\.'   # NOT a valid escape sequence in **regular** Python single-quoted strings
"\."   # NOT a valid escape sequence in **regular** Python double-quoted strings
```

They'll cause a warning like this:

> DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence `\.`

All of these, however, ARE allowed and are equivalent:

```py
# Use a DOUBLE BACK-SLASH in Python _regular_ strings
'\\.'  # **regular** Python single-quoted string
"\\."  # **regular** Python double-quoted string

# Use a SINGLE BACK-SLASH in Python _raw_ strings 
r'\.'  # Python single-quoted **raw** string
r"\."  # Python double-quoted **raw** string
```

### Explanation

Keep in mind, the backslash (`\`) char itself must be escaped in Python if used inside of a regular string (`'some string'` or `"some string"`) instead of a [*raw* string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) (`r'some string'` or `r"some string"`). So, keep in mind the type of string you are using. To escape the dot or period (`.`) inside a regular expression in a regular python string, therefore, you must also escape the backslash by using a double backslash (`\\`), making the total escape sequence for the `.` in the regular expression this: `\\.`, as shown in the examples above.

### References

1. MAIN AND OFFICIAL REFERENCE: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals
   [image]
2. [answer by @Sean Hammond] [How to fix "<string> DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335970/how-to-fix-string-deprecationwarning-invalid-escape-sequence-in-python/52335971#52335971)

   > If you want to put a literal `\` in a string you have to use `\\`

Answer (score 1):

to escape non-alphanumeric characters of string variables, including dots, you could use **`re.escape`**:

```
import re

expression = 'whatever.v1.dfc'
escaped_expression = re.escape(expression)
print(escaped_expression)
```

output:

> `whatever\.v1\.dfc`

you can use the escaped expression to find/match the string literally.

Answer (score 0):

So first you need to construct your regex string.
For example this one matches your need:

`^.*?\btest\b\.\bthis\b.*?`

Next you need to put it into Python code:

```
import re

input_string = "blah blah blah test.this@gmail.com blah blah"
regex_string = "^.*?\\btest\\b\\.\\bthis\\b.*?"
if re.search(regex_string, input_string):
    print("match :-)")
else:
    print("no match :-(")
```

To understand what the regex does, you can play with that on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score -3):

This expression,

```
(?<=\s|^)[^.\s]+\.[^.\s]+(?=@)
```

might also work OK for those specific types of input strings.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pu5BIY/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

expression = r'(?<=^|\s)[^.\s]+\.[^.\s]+(?=@)'
string = '''
blah blah blah test.this@gmail.com blah blah
blah blah blah test.this @gmail.com blah blah
blah blah blah test.this.this@gmail.com blah blah
'''

matches = re.findall(expression, string)

print(matches)
```

#### Output

```
['test.this']
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Pu5BIY/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Pu5BIY/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score -4):

In javascript you have to use `\\.` to match a dot.

Example

```
"blah.tests.zibri.org".match('test\\..*')
null
```

and

```
"blah.test.zibri.org".match('test\\..*')
["test.zibri.org", index: 5, input: "blah.test.zibri.org", groups: undefined]
```

Comment: it asks for python not JS