# Regular expressions in Django

Tags: python, regex, django, url, django-urls

I am new to django and I am having problems with my views. I would like to get all the urls with the extension .html go to a view ...app.views.test

I have:

```
url(r'^\. html$',views.test)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just check the ending:

```
url(r'\.html$', views.test)
```

Note that a dot needs to be [*escaped with a backslash*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989640/regular-expression-to-match-a-dot) since the dot has a [special meaning](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> '.' (Dot.)
>
> In the default mode, this matches any character except a
>   newline.