# Splitting a word where "." occurs

Tags: java

I need to be able to split a single word string like "x.y" into an array of size 2 where the "." occurs, so the array would look like ["x", "y"]. What I've tried is:

```
String word = "hello.world";
String[] split = word.split(".")
return split.length == 2;
```

but this seems to just return an empty array (false). How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repalce this

```
String[] split = word.split(".")
```

with

```
String[] split = word.split("\\.")
```

`.` (dot) has a special meaning in regex so you need to escape it if you want to use it as a literal to split.

Comment: [`.dot has a special meaning`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989640/regular-expression-to-match-a-dot)

Comment: Ah, such a silly oversight. Thank you!