# Avoid pandas str.replace using a regex

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, replace

I have the following pandas dataframe. Say it has two columns: `id` and `search_term`:

```
id       search_term
37651    inline switch
```

I do:

```
train['search_term'] = train['search_term'].str.replace("in."," in. ")
```

expecting that the dataset above is unaffected, but I get in return for this dataset:

```
id       search_term
37651    in.  in.  switch
```

which means `inl` is replaced by `in.` and `ine` is replaced by `in.`, as if I where using a regular expression, where dot means any character.

How do I rewrite the first command so that, literally, `in.` is replaced by `in.` but any `in` not followed by a dot is untouched, as in:

```
a = 'inline switch'
a = a.replace('in.','in. ')

a
>>> 'inline switch'
```

Comment: What is you actual desired output?

Comment: sorry, I want to replace 'dot' literally. I posted an answer below as I found a good post on the regular expression for 'dot'. the problem is that str.replace() in a dataframe uses regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the `.`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'search_term': ['inline switch', 'in.here']})
>>> df.search_term.str.replace('in\\.', 'in. ')
0    inline switch
1          in. here
Name: search_term, dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks Ami. I see you escaped the . in the first argument, but what about the second? if you want to literally replace 'in.' by 'in. ' should you then use str.replace('in\\.', 'in\\. ') or str.replace('in\\.', 'in. ')?

Comment: @AlejandroSimkievich It would seem logical, but no. See the updated example above. Only the dot in the first string is interpreted as a regex character (which must be escaped).

Answer (score 5):

The version 0.23 or newer, the `str.replace()` got a new option for switching regex.
Following will simply turn it off.

```py
df.search_term.str.replace('in.', 'in. ', regex=False)
```

Will results in:

```py
0    inline switch
1         in. here
Name: search_term, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

and here is the answer: regular expression to match a dot.

str.replace() in pandas indeed uses regex, so that:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str.replace('in.', ' in. ')
```

is not comparable to:

```
a.replace('in.', ' in. ')
```

the latter does not use regex. So use '\.' instead of '.' in a statement that uses regex if you really mean dot and not any character.

[Regular Expression to match a dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989640/regular-expression-to-match-a-dot)

Comment: Note, however, that you can still use regex expressions, while stating that a dot has no special meaning.