# str.replace with special character "(*)"

Tags: python, pandas

I have some column s in a dataframe with (*) on some of the data headers. When I do

```
data.columns = data.columns.str.replace('(*)','')
```

I get the following error.

```
  File "C:\Users\ED397JT\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\object_array.py", line 156, in _str_replace
    pat = re.compile(pat, flags=flags)

  File "C:\Users\ED397JT\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 252, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)

  File "C:\Users\ED397JT\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 304, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)

  File "C:\Users\ED397JT\Anaconda3\lib\sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)

  File "C:\Users\ED397JT\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 948, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)

  File "C:\Users\ED397JT\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,

  File "C:\Users\ED397JT\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 834, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)

  File "C:\Users\ED397JT\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,

  File "C:\Users\ED397JT\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 668, in _parse
    raise source.error("nothing to repeat",

error: nothing to repeat
```

What can I do?

Comment: Either set `regex=False`, or escape the `*` with `\ `. Pandas is attempting to use regex to make the replacements, and thinks you're passing a regex pattern, and `*` is the repetition symbol in regular expressions: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid pandas str.replace using a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296993/avoid-pandas-str-replace-using-a-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

str.replace takes a regular expression and * is a metacharacter it is trying to interpret. Try escaping it like so:

```
data.columns.str.replace('(\*)', '')
```

or indicate that you aren't using regex:

```
data.columns.str.replace('(*)', '', regex=False)
```