# Concerning the re.sub of python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

```
re.sub(r'.\d+.',r'.','ab.12.c')
#or
re.sub(r'\.\d+\.',r'.','ab.12.c')
```

give `ab.c`, while

```
re.sub(r'.\d+.',r'\.','ab.12.c')
#or
re.sub(r'\.\d+\.',r'\.','ab.12.c')
```

give  `ab\\.c`.

The former gives the result I want but shouldn't `.` be escaped in the regex, as in the latter?

Comment: If you plan to match a literal `.`, you should escape it. Otherwise, it will match any character but a newline (`.` included)

Comment: See [*Regular Expression to match a dot*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989640/regular-expression-to-match-a-dot)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it seems the problem is at the replace string. Why that dot shouldn't be escaped?

Comment: Aha, that dot is in the replacement pattern, it is not in a regular expression.

Comment: So the replace string is a normal str and `re.sub(r'\.\d+\.',r'.','ab.12.c') ` is the correct one. I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming there _were_ a wildcard in the replacement string, what character should end up in the result? Also, isn't your first and second output the same, or am I missing some subtle difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it seems the problem is at the replace string. Why that dot shouldn't
>   be escaped? – Lee

Aha, that dot is in the replacement pattern, it is not in a regular expression. – Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: If Wiktor posts an answer, I'll select it.