# Replace . with / in groovy

Tags: groovy

I know this is a very specific question by I didn't manage to do the replacement myself, I need to replace this string in groovy:

**com.pantest** in **com/pantest**.

I tried this:

```
groupId =com.pantest
def mavenGroupID = groupId.replaceAll('.','/')
```

And this is what I get in the output:

```
echo mavenGroupID is //////////
mavenGroupID is //////////
```

Is the dot (.) is some kind of special character? I tried to escape it using **** but it also didn't work.

Comment: `public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) {  ` , try `\.`

Comment: based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989640/regular-expression-to-match-a-dot 
should works as suggested escaping with `\` so `\.` or put it to match group via `[.]` (replaceAll is taking regex as input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) is taking regex as the input, so it means you need to escape dot at least, but actually, you have also to escape escaping char- backslash `\` 
(more clues at [Regular Expression to match a dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989640/regular-expression-to-match-a-dot))

so, you can do it like follows:

```
def test = "aaa.bbb.ccc"
//want to replace ., need to use escape char \, but it needs to be escaped as well , so \\
println test.replaceAll('\\.','/')
```

Output is as requested `aaa/bbb/ccc`

> `replaceAll('\\.','/')` is the key