# How to remove commas from ALL the column in pandas at once

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace

I have a data frame where all the columns are supposed to be numbers. While reading it, some of them were read with commas.  I know a single column can be fixed by

```py
df['x']=df['x'].str.replace(',','')
```

However, this works only for series objects and not for entire data frame. Is there an elegant way to apply it to entire data frame since every single entry in the data frame should be a number.

P.S: To ensure I can `str.replace`, I have first converted the data frame to str by using

```py
df.astype('str')
```

So I understand, I will have to convert them all to numeric once the comma is removed.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Numeric columns have no `,`, so converting to strings is not necessary, only use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `regex=True` for substrings replacement:

```
df = df.replace(',','', regex=True)
```

Or:

```
df.replace(',','', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

And last convert strings columns to numeric, thank you @anki_91:

```
c = df.select_dtypes(object).columns
df[c] = df[c].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
```

Comment: is `regex=True` needed here? I think I'm missing something

Comment: ok, got it: `to_replace: [...], str: string **exactly** matching to_replace will be replaced with value`

Comment: Thanks @Jezrael.  This works great. I would have never figured out the last part which converts strings columns to numeric, on my own!

Comment: when I tried the same for replacing dot , this line is replacing all cells with empty values and am getting an empty dataframe.
df.replace('.' , '' , regex=True, inplace=True). Why is '.' matching with every entry?

Comment: @SuperUser - You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13989661/2901002)

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can simplely do:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', ''))
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to manipulate just one column:

```
df.column_name = df.column_name.apply(lambda x : x.replace(',',''))
```

Comment: OP explicitly asked about manipulating the entire DataFrame, after showing a way to manipulate just one column. So this does not help.