# replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'regex' even though I have it as a string

Tags: regex, string

I have commas in a column which I want to remove using regex.This link shows how to do so. The problem is I am getting this error in the image. The documenation says it must be a string, which mine is as you can see in the dtypes.  *If this is True then to_replace must be a string.* Why I am I still getting this error? Thanks! [How to remove commas from ALL the column in pandas at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947333/how-to-remove-commas-from-all-the-column-in-pandas-at-once)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your current syntax for calling `replace` on the entire data frame looks correct to me.  The problem may be that the `count` column is numeric, and hence it makes no sense to be calling `replace` on it.  Try calling `replace` only on the `tags` column:

```py
count_df["tags"] = count_df["tags"].str.replace(',', '')
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I tried that but got TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable. I tried to approach with spark and this worked.
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, concat, col, lit
import re

commaRep = udf(lambda x: re.sub(',$|^,','', x))
count_df_2=count_df.withColumn('tags',commaRep('tags'))
count_df_2.show(3)

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, concat, col, lit
import re

commaRep = udf(lambda x: re.sub(',$|^,','', x))
count_df_2=count_df.withColumn('tags',commaRep('tags'))
count_df_2.show(3)
```