# Return the positions of date cells for ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '2020-4-')

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Given a dataframe with multiple messy date columns as follows:

```
  id       date1       date2       date3
0   1   2020-5-10   2020-5-18   2021-5-17
1   2   2020.4.20   2020/5/20   2023/5/19
2   4   2020年5月7日   2020年5月20   2023年5月19
3   5  2020年4月23日    2020/5/1   2022/4/30
4   6  2020年4月12日  2020年4月20日   2022/4/19
5   7   2020年5月8日   2020年5月8日   2022年5月8日
6   8   2020年5月3号   2020年5月8号   2022年5月3号
7  12  2020—05—10  2020—05—11  2021—05—10
8  13  2020—05—08  2020—05—15  2022—05—14
9  14  2020年3月15日  2020年3月15日  2023年3月14日
```

I have written a `date_manipulate` function to convert them into standard dates, which is the format `%Y-%m-%d`.

```
def date_manipulate(x):
    x = x.str.strip()
    x = x.str.replace(' ', '')
    x = x.str.replace('年', '-')
    x = x.str.replace('月', '-')
    x = x.str.replace('日', '')
    x = x.str.replace('号', '')
    x = x.str.replace('.', '-')
    x = x.str.replace('—', '-')
    x = pd.to_datetime(x).dt.date.astype(str)
    return x

date_cols = ['date1', 'date2', 'date3']
df[date_cols].apply(date_manipulate)
```

But it raises a value error, however I don't know which date cell from orginal excel produce this error:

```
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '2020-4-')
```

How could I modify the code to return the positions of date cells to help me to check? Thanks.

Output from @jezrael's code:

```
                date1            date2              date3
1              2020.4.20  2020-05-20 00:00:00  2023-05-19 00:00:00
4             2020年4月23日  2020-05-01 00:00:00  2022-04-30 00:00:00
5             2020年4月12日           2020年4月20日  2022-04-19 00:00:00
16             2020年5月6日  2020-05-07 00:00:00            2022年5月8日
46   2020-03-20 00:00:00  2020-04-01 00:00:00  2022-03-31 00:00:00
48   2020-03-15 00:00:00  2020-03-20 00:00:00  2021-03-19 00:00:00
53   2020-04-01 00:00:00  2020-05-01 00:00:00  2025-04-30 00:00:00
54   2020-04-03 00:00:00  2020-04-03 00:00:00  2022-04-02 00:00:00
57   2020-04-14 00:00:00  2020-04-20 00:00:00  2021-04-19 00:00:00
58             2020年4月3日  2020-04-18 00:00:00           2022年4月17日
60   2020-04-30 00:00:00           2020年5月10号  2022-05-09 00:00:00
62             2020年5月7日  2020-05-06 00:00:00  2021-05-05 00:00:00
93             2020年5月2号  1900-01-05 02:52:48            2022年5-14
95             2020年5月5日           2020年5月10日  2022-05-09 00:00:00
96            2020年4月10日           2020年4月10日  2022-04-09 00:00:00
99   2020-05-11 00:00:00  2020-05-11 00:00:00  2022-05-10 00:00:00
121           2020年4月15号  2020-03-01 00:00:00           2023年2月28日
178           2020年4月30日              2020年4月  2022-02-28 00:00:00
180           2020年5月18日  2020-05-20 00:00:00  2022-05-19 00:00:00
186           2020年4月28日           2020年4月30日  2022-04-29 00:00:00
196           2020年5月18号  2020-05-20 00:00:00  2022-05-19 00:00:00
197           2020年3月18号           2020年3月18日  2022-02-28 00:00:00
231             2020-5-8  2020-05-08 00:00:00             2023-5-8
```

Out from `print(df.loc[mask.any(axis=1), mask.any().reindex(df.columns, fill_value=False)].to_dict('l'))`:

```
{'date1': ['2020.4.20', '2020年4月23日', '2020年4月12日', '2020年5月6日', datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 20, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 14, 0, 0), '2020年4月3日', datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 30, 0, 0), '2020年5月7日', '2020年5月2号', '2020年5月5日', '2020年4月10日', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 0, 0), '2020年4月15号', '2020年4月30日', '2020年5月18日', '2020年4月28日', '2020年5月18号', '2020年3月18号', '2020-5-8'], 'date2': [datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 1, 0, 0), '2020年4月20日', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 20, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 20, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 18, 0, 0), '2020年5月10号', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 6, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 5, 2, 52, 48), '2020年5月10日', '2020年4月10日', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0), '2020年4月', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 0, 0), '2020年4月30日', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 0, 0), '2020年3月18日', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 8, 0, 0)], 'date3': [datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 30, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 19, 0, 0), '2022年5月8日', datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2025, 4, 30, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 19, 0, 0), '2022年4月17日', datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 5, 0, 0), '2022年5-14', datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 10, 0, 0), '2023年2月28日', datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 28, 0, 0), '2023-5-8']}
```

Comment: do you know the encoding of the strings in the date columns? that could make cleaning easier...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, those are are manually filled dates, so it's quite messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For looking for row with wrong datetimes is possible a bit modify your solution - added `errors='coerce'` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for missing values if not parseable dates and then test missing values by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) with `any`:

```
print (df)
   id       date1       date2       date3
0   1   2020-5-10   2020-5-18   2021-5-17
1   2   2020.4.20   2020/5/20   2023/5/19
2   4   2020年5月7日   2020年5月20   2023年5月19
3   5  2020年4月23日    2020/5/1   2022/4/30
4   6  2020年4月12日  2020年4月20日   2022/4/19
5   7   2020年5月8日   2020年5月8日   2022年5月8日
6   8   2020年5月3号   2020年5月8号     2022年5月 <- error
7  12  2020—05—10  2020—05—11  2021—05—10
8  13  2020—05—08  2020—05—15  2022—05—14
9  14  2020年3月15日  2020年3月15日  2023年3月14日


def date_manipulate(x):
    x = x.str.strip()
    x = x.str.replace(' ', '')
    x = x.str.replace('年', '-')
    x = x.str.replace('月', '-')
    x = x.str.replace('日', '')
    x = x.str.replace('号', '')
    x = x.str.replace('.', '-')
    x = x.str.replace('—', '-')
    x = pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce')
    return x
```

Also is possible simflify function:

```
def date_manipulate(x):
    x = x.replace([' ', '日', '号'], '', regex=True)
    x = x.replace(['年','月','—', '\.'], '-', regex=True)
    x = pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce')
    return x
```

---

```
date_cols = ['date1', 'date2', 'date3']

mask = df[date_cols].apply(date_manipulate).isna()
print (df.loc[mask.any(axis=1), mask.any().reindex(df.columns, fill_value=False)])

     date3
6  2022年5月
```

Comment: I tried your code with my data, it returns same result `ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '2020-4-')`

Comment: @ahbon - I think you forget for `pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce')`

Comment: It seems using `pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce')` return many `NaN`s.

Comment: @ahbon - hmm, it depends of data, unfornuately. ;(

Comment: I have pasted the result on question from your new code. From the result, it seems two problems `2020-05-07 00:00:00` and `43910`

Comment: @ahbon - tested and problem with excel datetimes like `43910`

Comment: @ahbon - then with `2020年4日18日` and `2020年4月`

Comment: The cases you mentioned above I have edited from excel,  now one problem `2020-05-20 00:00:00`, any ideas how to deal with this issue?

Comment: @ahbon - Is possible convert output to dict? Like `df.loc[mask.any(axis=1), mask.any().reindex(df.columns, fill_value=False)].to_dict('l')` ? Because cannot testing correctly `2020-05-20 00:00:00`, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, still not working for `2020-05-20 00:00:00` type of data even after I add `x = pd.to_datetime(x).dt.date`.

Comment: @ahbon - Working on it.

Comment: Thanks, just FYI, I can convert them as 5 digit timestamp in Excel.

Comment: @ahbon - I found reason - there are datetimes, so if used `.str.strip()` it return `NaN`s :(

Comment: Ok, I use `.str.strip()` because there spaces in the date, ie: `2020 - 5 - 20`, etc.

Comment: You're right, when I comment `.str.strip()`, it works out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Last question, why did you use `'\.'` instead of `.`?

Comment: @ahbon - Because `.` is special regex characters, it seelct all values. So is necessary escape it `\.` for working like `.` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989640/regular-expression-to-match-a-dot)